# Java - Create in memory csv and convert to MultipartFile[]

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv

I have some data that I need to attach to an email as a csv file, I'm looking for a way to create the csv in memory, then pass to an existing function that only accepts attachments as MultipartFile[].

I got as far as saving a csv to disk, but have no idea how to skip that step / convert it to a MultipartFile[].

Comment: Not sure if overkill or not, but you could create a POST endpoint that has a MultipartFile param and then use RestTemplate to POST to that endpoint with your file

Answer (score 0):

I think you have different ways of doing this.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.support.ByteArrayMultipartFileEditor;

// read the csv file from disk
File csvFile = new File("/path/to/your/file.csv");
try(InputStream csvFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(csvFile)) {
 
    // create a ByteArrayMultipartFileEditor
    ByteArrayMultipartFileEditor byteArrayMultipartFileEditor = new ByteArrayMultipartFileEditor();
    
    // set the data in the byteArrayMultipartFileEditor
    byteArrayMultipartFileEditor.setValue(csvFileInputStream);
    
    // create a MultipartFile[]
    MultipartFile[] multipartFiles = {byteArrayMultipartFileEditor.getValue()};
    
    // pass the multipartFiles to your existing function
    yourFunction(multipartFiles);
}
```

`ByteArrayMultipartFileEditor` converts the inputStream to a `MultipartFile[]` named `multipartFiles` which can be passed to your existing function.

There is also this other way.

```
...
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile;
import java.nio.file.Files;

File csvFile = new File("/path/to/your/file.csv");
FileItem fileItem = new DiskFileItem("file", Files.probeContentType(csvFile.toPath()), false, csvFile.getName(), (int) csvFile.length(), csvFile.getParentFile());
CommonsMultipartFile multipartFile = new CommonsMultipartFile(fileItem);

yourFunction(new MultipartFile[] { multipartFile });
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: The second option looks much cleaner, but StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest says it requires a HttpServletRequest, but got a FileSystemResource.

Comment: You're right, I re-edited my answer. Let me know if this works, please.